# How to add prefix with default metrics in Prometheus metrics for c# Nuget Package prometheus-net.AspNetCore

Tags: c#, prometheus

I am trying to add `prefix` with default metrics of `prometheus` but for now there is no clue to add prefix with default metrics. For example default metric look like:

`http_requests_in_progress`

It should be like:

`prefix_http_requests_in_progress`

I am using Nuget Package:

`prometheus-net.AspNetCore 4.1.1`

I have initiated the sever like this:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
       try { app.UseMetricServer("/metrics"); app.UseHttpMetrics();  } catch (Exception ex) {  }        
 }
```